# Здравствуйте, помогите решить ошибку json

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, json, json-encode

Добрый день я отправляю запрос на то, чтобы данные записывались в бд, но это не происходит и выводит ошибку.

```
if (isset($_GET["id"]) && isset($_GET["price"]) ) { 

$wpdb->insert(
    'yl_paid_info',
    array('user_id' => $_GET["id"], 'price' => $_GET["price"], 'start_date' => date("m.d.y"), 'end_date' => $first_str),
    array('%d', '%d', '%s', '%s')
);
$result = array(
    'name' => $_GET["id"],
    'phonenumber' => $_GET["price"]
);
```

}

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      /* Article FructCode.com */
      $( document ).ready(function() {
          $("#btn").click(
              function(){
                  sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'ajax_form', '<?php echo plugins_url('paid-subscription/paid-new.php')?>');
                  return false; 
              }
          );
      });

      function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
          $.ajax({
              url:     url, //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php)
              type:     "GET", //метод отправки
              dataType: "html", //формат данных
              data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize(),  // Сеарилизуем объект
              success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
                  result = $.parseJSON(response);
                  $('#result_form').html(result);
              },
              error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
                  $('#result_form').html('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
              }
          });
      }
  });
```

```html
<form method="GET" id="ajax_form" action="" >
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="ID пользователя"></br></br>
    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Покупка"></br></br></br>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Добавить подписку"/>
</form>
<div id="result_form"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите в Chrome dev tools что приходит в ответ от AJAX

Comment: @WPPunk а что туда смотреть, там гарантированно 500.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вызвать файл `paid-subscription/paid-new.php`, и в нём использовать функции WordPress. Из воздуха они там сами по себе ниоткуда на возьмутся, надо инициализировать ядро WP. В результате - 500. Почитайте о том, как правильно строить ajax в WP: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Исключите вставки php кода из js.
2. Вы указываете что хотите получить HTML а потом парсите его как JSON.
   Если вы хотите отправить с сервера json, используйте `wp_send_json($result)` и установите `dataType` в json
3. Вы не можете записывать объект в html. Преобразуйте его в строку через `JSON.stringify`